# How to close the browser in selenium using Hot Keys?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> Selenium Webdriver v-3.0.1

I want to close the browser window using hot keys, I have tried following methods one by one but not working at all -

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+"w"));

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+"F4"));

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.F4));

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.F4);

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"F4");
```

How do I close browser other then `driver.close()` and `driver.quit` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure browser window should be active.

You can perform using actions

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.ALT);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.F4);
actions.keyUp(Keys.ALT);
actions.perform();
```

Same you can achieve using `Robot`. 
To get this code running you need to add,

```
import java.awt.Robot;

Robot robot = new Robot();
// press key Alt+F4
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
// relase key Alt+F4
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

If you do not use `driver.quit()` at the end of program, `WebDriver` session will not close properly and files would not be cleared off memory. This may result in memory leak errors.
Hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks for rapid response. But its not working at my end instead by using `Robot` My keyboard started awkward behaving, Its strange

Comment: Edited my answer, as delay should required and key release functionality added.

Comment: Glad to Help. Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have opened a single tab you can try below method:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"w");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
String killBrowser= Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.F4);
actions.sendKeys(killBrowser);
actions.perform();
```

Try this.